# Spring security automatically fills in name and username and issue with hashing passwords

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring project which involves logging in with credentials stored in the database. Now that seems to work just fine, the only thing is, whenever I go to the page to log in, it automatically fills in "jimi" as the username and some password without me even having typed in anything.

This is my xml configuration:

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <headers>
            <cache-control />
        </headers>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/user/login"
                    default-target-url="/home"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                    username-parameter="username"
                    password-parameter="password"
                    login-processing-url="/auth/login_check" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />


    </http>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>

        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                               users-by-username-query=
                                       "select email,password, enabled from user where email=?"
                               authorities-by-username-query=
                                       "select email, role from user_roles where email =?  " />
        </authentication-provider>

    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

spring-database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://connectionurl" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <import resource="spring-database.xml"/>
    <import resource="spring-security.xml"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

    <bean id="emf"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="medicapp" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="tm" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="emf" p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="tm"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="medicapp.*" />

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/mytheme/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Now for the issue with the hashing. As you can see, I have a BCrypt encoder bean declared in my spring-security.xml . However, when I try to use it, I can never log in. I can log in without it, however. I hashed a password using this password generator:

PasswordGenerator.java

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public class PasswordEncoderGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            String password = "123456";
            BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

            System.out.println(hashedPassword);


    }
}
```

I copy/paste the output from there in my database, but no luck

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards!

Comment: try clearing your browser cache.. if username password are there, it is the browser that is filling it not the spring application.

Comment: Was it really that simple...? Dear god, why didn't I think of this myself.

Do you also have an explanation for the encryption?

Answer (score 0):

What you did in the spring-security.xml is declare the password encoder as a bean but you have not told the spring security to use the password encoder to  use it for encoding the passwords.

What might be happening here would be, your password is not getting encoded before it is checked in the database thus your authentication fails.

Try this

```
 <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
```

Adding the this will tell the spring security to encode the password using this bean and then check the database for the matching user object.

Hope it may help

Comment: No, I did use it before, but it didn't work, thus I removed it to let my login work